# Any DVI splitters that can handle resolutions up to 2560x1440?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi

I have a computer that already has two monitors plugged into it.  I'm trying to add a third monitor that displays the same thing as one of them now.  The display I want to duplicate is 2560x1440. The only DVI splitters I've been able to find can only handle [1920x1200](http://www.kvmstuff.com/2-port-dvi-splitter-vda-series-1-dvi-in-to-2-dvi-out-single-link-active.html).

The monitors are each [Dell UltraSharp U2711 27”](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&sku=224-8284&redirect=1) so I'm open to converting to HDMI or DisplayPort and splitting that signal instead.

Does anyone know of a DVI (or DisplayPort, HDMI) splitter that can handle 2560x1440?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received the [thinklogical VDA-3](http://thinklogical.com/product.asp?ID=49) (Dual link 1:2) splitter -- awesome.  It's doing exactly what I need.   As of this writing, the web site has one set of specs for all three versions of the VDA device they sell and it only mentions handling up to video resolutions up to 1920x1200; however, the VDA-3 does handle 2560x1440.  I'm using it right now.

Answer (score 1):

That resolution requires full dual-link and it's doubtful you can split that adequately with inexpensive hardware.  While there MAY be such a product, I have never seen it and it will be very difficult to find because it's likely to be expensive and there's next to no market for it, to the extent that ADDING A VIDEO OUTPUT (an additional video card, probably) is probably going to be cheaper and easier.

Comment: It's not for home use so I'm not too concerned about the cost. I'm also looking at DVI-HDMI conversion and then splitting. The video card cannot be changed and another cannot be added.

Comment: @dwj - My point is that an expensive niche product may be VERY difficult to track down.  (I work for a company who specializes in high-end multiple monitor solutions where money is no object, and again, and I'm not aware of any such product.)  The inability to say, replace the card with a quad-output one is a pain though.  Any chance of just replacing the machine?  Hahaha

Comment: @Shinrai - Gotcha.  I have a lead on a device that claims to do what I want.  It'll be in my hands in two days; I'll post a follow-up when I see what it can do.  No go on the replacing the machine either -- it's just a piece of a larger system!

Comment: @dwj - Hope it works out and I'm interested to see if it does and what it is.  Best of luck.

Comment: @Shinrai: See the follow up answer I just posted.

Comment: @dwj - Sweet!  This is not a vendor I've ever heard of....looks like they do mostly image processing and range extension.  Glad it works!  (Also reassuring to see it's as expensive as I feared.)

Answer (score 0):

[Gefen](http://www.gefen.com/) also makes a [1->2 DL DVI Splitter](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=3571).  Looks to be roughly as expensive as the Thinklogical product.  Gefen's products tend to be expensive, but high-quality.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Dual link DVI Splitter. ThinkLogical makes one ( Part # VDA-3). I have used a couple of their products in the past and they work well.